# Foundations of Mathematics - Where to Start?

Tags: book-recommendation, foundations

I am interested in the foundations of mathematics. However, I don't know where to start.

From what I've read, the most popular foundational system for mathematics is Set Theory: ZFC specifically. ZFC is formulated using First-Order Logic. So, from these two things the obvious starting point for me is:

1. Learn (at least the basics of) First-Order Logic.
2. Start learning about ZFC.

My question: **What are the best (*relatively advanced*) textbooks for 1 and 2?** A textbook combining 1 and 2 would be ideal.

Comment: When you say "relatively advanced," what is your existing mathematical background, and what other mathematical interests do you have (e.g. are you familiar with real analysis? do you prefer analysis or abstract algebra? etc.)? This will help us give better-tailored answers.

Comment: Goldrei's *Classic Set Theory* covers the ZFC axioms in a manner intended for independent study, I really recommend it.  He also has a book *Propositional and predicate calculus: a model for argument* on logic.

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point is Halmos's [Naive Set Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1614271313).  It is "naive" in the sense that it does not use formal logic, so it may not satisfy your (1).  However it is a standard textbook in the field and very readable (and short), so I will recommend it.  Note that to formalize ZFC you will actually need second-order logic.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but I'd like to start with something relatively advanced. Do you have anything else to recommend?

Comment: No, I have not studied ZFC in that much detail myself.  I'd put Halmos at an 'intermediate' level - I believe it is intended for advanced undergrad math majors.

Answer (score 2):

For first-order logic, one standard reference is [Enderton](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384520). I'm also a fan of [Boolos, Burgess, and Jeffrey](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521701465), specifically chapters $9$ and $10$ (this is the text I learned from); incidentally, this book has a lot of material on computability theory which you can ignore for your purposes, although personally I recommend reading it as well *(admittedly, perhaps skipping chapters $5$ and $6$)*.

For set theory itself, my favorite text is [Kunen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444868399), but it's pretty dry. You may prefer something like [Ciesielski](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521594650).

Comment: When you say Kunen, do you mean his "Foundations of Mathematics." Also I was wondering about Boolos & al. They seem to base 9 and 10 on sequent calculus (and enthusiastically refer to it as a more advanced approach). How would you asses its place in mathematical logic. Thanks

Comment: @Andrew No, I meant his "introduction to independence proofs" (follow the link). As to sequent calculus, I personally find it the best of the formal deductive systems, but I'm not a proof theorist; ultimately, as long as you're comfortable with one it won't be too hard to translate between them.